# Mysql Deadlock in Stored Procedure,composite unique key

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, deadlock, unique-constraint, auto-commit

I have a table with composite unique key(uniqueness on combination of 3 columns.) Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `userreview` (
 `cid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `conid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `userid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `flag` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `updatedat` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON 
  UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid` 
  (`cid`,`conid`,`userid`)
 ) ;
```

Below is stored procedure .

```
          CREATE  PROCEDURE `testdeadlock`(IN pconid   BIGINT(12), IN pcid 
        BIGINT(12), IN puserid BIGINT(12),IN pflag INT(1))
        BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
         ROLLBACK;
         RESIGNAL;
       END;

      START TRANSACTION;  
      IF pflag = 1 THEN

       INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
                  VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid,1)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 1;
               /*update operation in table 1*/
       ELSEIF pflag = 0 THEN

         INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid)
                  VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 0;
             /*update operation in table 2*/
          ELSEIF pflag = 2 THEN

          INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid)
                  VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 2;
             /*update operation in table 3*/
       end if;
      COMMIT;
      end;
```

When this procedure is executing from client side(using node.js),sometime it occurs deadlock when concurrent transactions are going to execute on same rows.Though there is unique index still facing deadlock problem. Is there any suggestion to avoid deadlock?

Deadlock result:-

```
            LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
        ------------------------
        2018-07-06 16:55:51 0x2b0b08e99700
        *** (1) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 102648166, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
        mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
        LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
        MySQL thread id 108948, OS thread handle 47323865503488, query id 242017676 10.0.3.130 numbertankroot update
        INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
                VALUES( NAME_CONST('pcid',8157), NAME_CONST('pconid',3158), NAME_CONST('puserid',85217))
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 0
        *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 735 page no 17308 n bits 256 index idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid of table `userreview` trx id 102648166 lock_mode X waiting
        Record lock, heap no 183 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
         0: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
         1: len 8; hex 000000000005af9f; asc         ;;
         2: len 8; hex 00000000000bd0b7; asc         ;;
         3: len 6; hex 0000061e4965; asc     Ie;;
         4: len 7; hex 2800000eb42873; asc (    (s;;
         5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
         6: len 1; hex 84; asc  ;;
         7: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
         8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
         9: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
         10: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
         11: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
         12: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
         13: len 6; hex 5b3f9f170000; asc [?    ;;
         14: len 6; hex 5b3f9f17213e; asc [?  !>;;

        *** (2) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 102648170, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
        mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
        4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
        MySQL thread id 108960, OS thread handle 47326394160896, query id 242017689 10.0.3.130 numbertankroot update
        INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
                VALUES( NAME_CONST('pcid',8157), NAME_CONST('pconid',3158), NAME_CONST('puserid',85217))
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 1
        *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
        RECORD LOCKS space id 735 page no 17308 n bits 256 index `idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid` of table `userreview` trx id 102648170 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
        Record lock, heap no 183 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
         0: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
         1: len 8; hex 000000000005af9f; asc         ;;
         2: len 8; hex 00000000000bd0b7; asc         ;;
         3: len 6; hex 0000061e4965; asc     Ie;;
         4: len 7; hex 2800000eb42873; asc (    (s;;
         5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
         6: len 1; hex 84; asc  ;;
         7: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
         8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
         9: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
         10: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
         11: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
         12: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
         13: len 6; hex 5b3f9f170000; asc [?    ;;
         14: len 6; hex 5b3f9f17213e; asc [?  !>;;

        *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 735 page no 17308 n bits 256 index `idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid` of table  `userreview` trx id 102648170 lock_mode X waiting
        Record lock, heap no 183 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
         0: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
         1: len 8; hex 000000000005af9f; asc         ;;
         2: len 8; hex 00000000000bd0b7; asc         ;;
         3: len 6; hex 0000061e4965; asc     Ie;;
         4: len 7; hex 2800000eb42873; asc (    (s;;
         5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
         6: len 1; hex 84; asc  ;;
         7: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
         8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
         9: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
         10: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
         11: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
         12: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
         13: len 6; hex 5b3f9f170000; asc [?    ;;
         14: len 6; hex 5b3f9f17213e; asc [?  !>;;

        *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: Why you use IF-ELSEIF chain instead of `IF pflag IN (0,1,2) THEN INSERT INTO userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag) VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid, CASE WHEN pflag=1 THEN 1 ELSE flag END) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = pflag;`

Comment: One more - the `INSERT .. ODKU` do not provide `IGNORE`. [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) Because if duplicate occurs, it is ignored, the record is simply discarded (*With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs*, [INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)), and no ODKU executed.

Comment: @Akina,there are some operations based on pflag that's why i am using IF-ELSEIF. And this type of deadlock occurs when multiple threads are going to execute this stored procedure.

Comment: And, why have the explicit transaction -- you execute only one IODKU, and it is atomic.  Simplify the stored proc (or get rid of it); your problem may go away.